# How to make random background color generator with "Generate" button in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make random background color generator with "Generate" button in HTML/JavaScript.

It is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <head>
      <title>Random Background Color Generator</title>
    </head>
    <script>
    function random_bg_color() {
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var bgColor = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
      console.log(bgColor);
      document.body.style.background = bgColor;
    }
    random_bg_color();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But my code have no "Generate" button.

I want to know how can I add "Generate" button to my code.

Comment: _"But my code have no "Generate" button"_ - Then add one? o.O

Comment: `document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = location.reload();` doesn't make sense. `location.reload()` will, as the name suggests, reload the current page (and doesn't return anything)

Comment: I don't want to reload... I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's missing is this:

```
<button onclick="random_bg_color()">Generate</button>
```

I suppose we just solved your school assignment.

Comment: Lol..... The author should have revised his book before asking. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you that what actually you wanted

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}



function setRandomColor() {
  $("#colorpad").css("background-color", getRandomColor());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colorpad" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:#000">

</div>
<button onclick="setRandomColor()">Generate</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work because the function isn't called;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <head>
      <title>Random Background Color Generator</title>
    </head>
    <script>
    function random_bg_color() {
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var bgColor = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
      console.log(bgColor);
      document.body.style.background = bgColor;
    }
    
    </script>
    <button onclick="random_bg_color();">Generate</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just add the `onclick="random_bg_color();"` and you won't have to reload the entire page just to change the background.

Answer (score 0):

Just add html button with onclick function to it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
    <head>
      <title>Random Background Color Generator</title>
    </head>
    <script>
    function random_bg_color() {
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var bgColor = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
      console.log(bgColor);
      document.body.style.background = bgColor;
    }
    random_bg_color();
    </script>
    <button onclick="random_bg_color()">Generate random color</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Adding this below line would solve your problem

> `<button onclick="random_bg_color()">Generate random color</button>`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you were trying to do was to build a button on the click that will change randomly your body-color. Actually, you can use it as shown below.

```html
<button onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#'+(Math.floor(Math.random()*999))
">Click me!</button>
```

**strong text**